# Log4J: unable to delete old files with IfFileName

Tags: logging, log4j

I am using Log4J 2.16. I am facing a problem when wanting to delete older log4j files.
Below is the Log4J properties file.

If I remove "IfFileName", then it deletes other log4j files also which are 40 days old. But with add "IfFileName", does not delete any file.

Please let me know, what I am missing here.

```
name=PropertiesConfig
# Name of the directory where the logs will be saved.
property.directoryname=/var/log/tomcat9/application

# alert is set to be a DailyRollingFileAppender using a PatternLayout.
appender.alert.type = RollingFile
appender.alert.name = alert
appender.alert.fileName = ${directoryname}/alert.log
appender.alert.filePattern = ${directoryname}/alert%d{MM-dd-yyyy}.%i.log
appender.alert.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.alert.layout.pattern = [%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level BT4: %logger{36} - %msg%n
appender.alert.policies.type = Policies
appender.alert.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.alert.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.alert.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.alert.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.alert.policies.size.size=10MB
appender.alert.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.alert.strategy.max = 20
####
appender.alert.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.alert.strategy.action.type = Delete
appender.alert.strategy.action.basePath = ${directoryname}/
appender.alert.strategy.action.maxDepth = 1
appender.alert.strategy.action.condition.type = IfFileName
appender.alert.strategy.action.condition.glob = alert*.log.gz
appender.alert.strategy.action.ifLastModified.type = IfLastModified
appender.alert.strategy.action.ifLastModified.age = 40D
####

appender.alert.filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
appender.alert.filter.threshold.level = ALL

# Root loggers.
rootLogger.level = ALL
rootLogger.appenderRef.alert.ref = alert
```

Comment: According to your configuration there are no files matching `alert*.log.gz`. Did you mean `alert*.log`?

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz, I didn't notice this till now. Previous day log files are renamed to alert*.log.gz, although I don't have 'gz' specified in the configuration.